# JPA persisting object despite validation failure

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I am having a problem where a model object is being merged with the database despite me not actually requesting it.
I am using Spring 3.1.2 and Hibernate 3.6.6

Here is my model object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ModelObject")
@Cacheable(true)
public class ModelObject implements Identifiable, PersonAssociation<MatrixReport> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2252419245370455982L;

@Transient
private Map<String, String> allComments = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "MR_ID")
private Integer id;

@NotNull(groups = { Draft.class, Complete.class })
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fkSubject")
private Person subject;

@NotNull(groups = { Draft.class, Complete.class })
@Column(name = "DateCreated")
private Date created;

@NotNull(groups = { Complete.class })
@Column(name = "DateCompleted")
private Date completed;

@NotNull(groups = { Draft.class, Complete.class })
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fkCompleter")
private Person completer;

@NotNull(groups = { Draft.class, Complete.class })
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fkCompleterGenericAppointment")
private ValidGenericAppointment completerAppointment;

@NotNull(groups = { Draft.class, Complete.class })
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fkCompleterRank")
private ValidRank completerRank;

@NotNull(groups = { Draft.class, Complete.class })
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fkCompleterTerritory")
private ValidTerritory completerTerritory;

@NotEmpty(groups = { Complete.class })
@Column(name = "Comment")
private String comment;

@NotNull(groups = { Draft.class, Complete.class })
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fkAuthenticatedCreator")
private AuthenticatedUserEntity authenticatedCreator;

@NotNull(groups = { Draft.class, Complete.class })
@Column(name = "IsDraft")
private boolean draft;

@NotNull(groups = { Complete.class })
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fkNextAppointment")
private ValidGenericAppointment nextAppointment;

@NotNull(groups = { Complete.class })
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fkUltimateAppointment")
private ValidGenericAppointment ultimateAppointment;

/* getter and setter methods... */

}
```

Here is my controller method that runs when a post request from the html form associated with this model object is made:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView saveDraftReport(@ModelAttribute("report") @Valid MatrixReport report, BindingResult result,
                Model model, Locale locale) {

            boolean valid;
            // Add the current rank of the completer to the report
            if (report.getCompleter() != null) {
                report.setCompleterRank(report.getCompleter().getOfficer().getCurrentRank().getRank());
            }
            if (report.isDraft()) {
                report.setCompleted(null);
                valid = this.validationUtils.isValid(result, report, locale, Draft.class);
            } else {
                report.setCompleted(new Date());
                valid = this.validationUtils.isValid(result, report, locale, Complete.class);
            }

            if (!valid) {      /* everything up to this point seems to be going as expected - the object is properly validating.  */
                return createMav(result.getModel());
            }

            if (valid && !result.hasErrors() && report.getId() != null) {
                this.matrixReportService.persistReport(report);
                if (!report.isDraft()) {
                    return createMav(result, "redirect:/app/matrix_reports_submitted.jsp?sub=1");
                }
            } else if (valid && !result.hasErrors() && report.getId() == null) {
                report = this.matrixReportService.persistReport(report);
                return createMav(result, "redirect:edit?reportId=" + report.getId());
            }
            return createMav(result.getModel());
        }
```

The "valid" flag is setting properly but the object is persisted whether or not validation fails.
The object seems to be saving after the user is redirected to the JSP. At the top of the page i set the bean variables below:

```
    <c:set target="${requestContext.pictureBean}" property="id" value="${personId}" />
    <c:set var="image" value="${requestContext.pictureBean.pictures[0]}" />
```

These variables require use of the repository layer and it would seem that the model object is saving when that layer is accessed. I have a feeling the problem could lie with transactions, but that doesn't answer why it is only happening with this model object. To illustrate why i believe this, i placed a PreUpdate listener in my model object - here is the result of a Thread.dumpStack within that:

```
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1223)
    at com.example.model.matrixreport.MatrixReport.preMatrixUpdate(MatrixReport.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.BeanCallback.invoke(BeanCallback.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EntityCallbackHandler.callback(EntityCallbackHandler.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EntityCallbackHandler.preUpdate(EntityCallbackHandler.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3FlushEntityEventListener.invokeInterceptor(EJB3FlushEntityEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.handleInterception(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:76)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at com.example.repository.PersonManager$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$898c8f79.findById(<generated>)
    at com.example.security.guards.AbstractObjectGuard.findById(AbstractObjectGuard.java:213)
    at com.example.presentation.beans.PersonBean.getPerson(PersonBean.java:51)
    at com.example.presentation.beans.PictureBean.getPictures(PictureBean.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.apache.jsp.app.resources.includes.info_005fpanel_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fset_005f5(info_005fpanel_jsp.java:435)
    at org.apache.jsp.app.resources.includes.info_005fpanel_jsp._jspService(info_005fpanel_jsp.java:111)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:314)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:171)
    at org.apache.jsp.app.matrix_005fedit_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fimport_005f3(matrix_005fedit_jsp.java:1300)
    at org.apache.jsp.app.matrix_005fedit_jsp._jspService(matrix_005fedit_jsp.java:295)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.salvationarmy.commons.filters.ApplicationContextFilter.doFilter(ApplicationContextFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:95)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.salvationarmy.commons.filters.ApplicationContextFilter.doFilter(ApplicationContextFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

thanks.

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong with the code you have posted.  Have you tried running in debug mode and tracing line by line?  I suspect something is being executed that you believe is not being executed outside of the code you have posted.  It might be worth noting if you load the record from the database and modify it from your form data within a transaction/session, the data will be immediately modified in the database despite not calling persist or merge.  I don't think that is happening here tho.

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was to do with transactions. I was calling into a @ Transactional annotated method that wasn't set as readOnly=true and the changes to my model object were being persisted when the method executed even though it was unrelated - possibly because it was part of the same session? Actually, I don't know 100% why... Beware of nested @ Transactional-s as well...